# How to set message in Scala custom exception?

Tags: scala, exception

I have the following trait:

```
trait ServiceException extends Exception {

  val message: String

  val nestedException: Throwable

}
```

And exceptions which look like this:

```
case class NoElementFoundException(message: String = "error.NoElementFoundException",
                                        nestedException: Throwable = null) extends ServiceException
```

The problem is that if I have a method like this:

```
def bla(exception: Throwable) = exception.getMessage
```

And I pass this method my `NoElementFoundException`, then `getMessage` will return `null`.

Probably I could easily fix this by removing the trait and just extending from `Exception`:

```
case class NoElementFoundException(message: String = "error.NoElementFoundException",
                                            nestedException: Throwable = null) extends Exception(message)
```

However, is there a way to keep the trait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the methods getMessage and getCause in your class to return your properties instead of the ones from the Exception base class.

```
case class NoElementFoundException(override val message: String = "error.NoElementFoundException",
                                   override val nestedException: Throwable = null) extends ServiceException {
  override def getMessage: String = message

  override def getCause: Throwable = nestedException
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming (although not sure) that you don't really want your `ServiceException`s to have new public methods other than the ones provided by Exception (e.g. `getMessage`, `getCause`).

If that's the case, you can make *extenders* of `ServiceException` extend `Exception` without making `ServiceException` extend it itself:

```
// "Marker" trait (no methods), extenders must also extend Exception
trait ServiceException { _: Exception => }

// extend Exception with ServiceException
case class NoElementFoundException(message: String = "error.NoElementFoundException",
                                   nestedException: Throwable = null)
      extends Exception(message, nestedException) with ServiceException

// now you can use Exception.getMessage without "duplicating" it into ServiceException:
val exception = NoElementFoundException()
println(exception.getMessage) // prints error.NoElementFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect this trait as it is to lead *only* to confusion, since `Exception`s already have messages and causes. I'd replace it with

```
trait ServiceException { _: Exception =>
  def message: String = getMessage
  def nestedException: Throwable = getCause
}
```

or to enable these methods to be called on all `Throwable`s,

```
implicit class ThrowableExtensions(self: Exception) {
  def message: String = self.getMessage
  def nestedException: Throwable = self.getCause
}
```

(in that case, if you still want `ServiceException`, it'll be just an empty marker trait).